# jQuery Self Contained Object Applying css

Tags: jquery

I am creating my jQuery element like this:

```
 var addLink = $("<a/>",
        {
            click: function () { }, 
            css:{}
        });
```

How can I apply css to change the color of the text?

UPDATE 1:

I can do the following but looking for a self contained model.

```
 var addLink = $("<a/>",
        {
            click: function () { }
        }).css("color","blue");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var addLink = $("<a/>", {
                  click: function () { }, 
                  css: { color: 'red' },
                  text: "anchorText"   
              });
```

You can specify any style you want to set as key/value pair in the object.

Comment: How can I add text also like the text for the link?

Comment: Thanks! For some reason this syntax is not working. The text is not assigned and also events do not fire. Maybe because MS Ajax lib might be doing something funky!

Comment: Unfortunately, the app I am working on does not show requests in Fiddler. It is all client based and overly complicated!